# Is it possible to programatically add plugins to a Bukkit server properly?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit, spigot

I am currently working on a Minecraft plugin using the Bukkit API. The plugin needs to, at runtime, add additional plugins to the server programatically. In [`SimplePluginManager`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/stash/projects/SPIGOT/repos/bukkit/browse/src/main/java/org/bukkit/plugin/SimplePluginManager.java), used by the [`CraftServer`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/stash/projects/SPIGOT/repos/craftbukkit/browse/src/main/java/org/bukkit/craftbukkit/CraftServer.java) class to load Java plugins, there is a method called [`registerInterface()`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/stash/projects/SPIGOT/repos/bukkit/browse/src/main/java/org/bukkit/plugin/SimplePluginManager.java#76) which takes in a class that implements the [`PluginLoader`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/stash/projects/SPIGOT/repos/bukkit/browse/src/main/java/org/bukkit/plugin/PluginLoader.java) interface. I was able to implement this interface myself for a class, and was able to call `registerInterface()` with no issues.

However, by the time `onLoad()` is called for my plugin, calling `registerInterface()` will do nothing. I know that this is because the [`loadPlugins()` method has already been called](https://hub.spigotmc.org/stash/projects/SPIGOT/repos/craftbukkit/browse/src/main/java/org/bukkit/craftbukkit/CraftServer.java#420), so registering an interface then means nothing will occur. I tried getting around this by simply calling [`loadPlugins()`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/stash/projects/SPIGOT/repos/bukkit/browse/src/main/java/org/bukkit/plugin/SimplePluginManager.java#113) again; with the argument for the directory being my plugin's parent directory (i.e., `/plugins`). This somewhat works, but it results in previously loaded plugins being loaded and registered *again*.

I know that [`loadPlugin()`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/stash/projects/SPIGOT/repos/bukkit/browse/src/main/java/org/bukkit/plugin/SimplePluginManager.java#378) exists, which just loads a single plugin file. This works, but looking at its implementation in `SimplePluginManager` seems to reveal that it lacks any dependency validation/resolution/etc. That is only done by `loadPlugins()`.

**With that, my question is:** How can one properly add plugins to a Bukkit server at runtime from another plugin programatically? If you need any more information on the problem, please ask me in the comments and I will happily update the question. Thank you!

Comment: I mean there are plugins that do this for you like PlugmanX. I've tried looking into this myself and when I tried to do it, it was very tricky and finicky. You could try reverse engineering some plugins like PlugmanX. If you really want to persue this I might be able to try to continue what I was doing one time and report back to you how I did it. That is, if I can figure it out

Comment: That sounds great, I appreciate the tip. Thank you!